# Get element height and assign it to next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I would like to get the current height of an element, then assign the height to the next element and so on..

For example

```
<ul>
   <li class="elem1">Element here </li> 
   <li class="elem2">Element here </li>  
   <li class="elem3">Element here </li>
</ul>
```

Before:

```
elem1 = 100px
elem2 = 300px
elem3 = 150px
```

After:

```
elem1 = 100px (preserve it's height)
elem2 = 100px (will have the height from elem 1 which is 100px)
elem3 = 300px (will have the height of elem 2 which is 300px)
```

jquery code:

```
$('ul li').each(function(index){
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.next().css('height', elem.height()+'px');
});
```

It's not working. Kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Because you are changing the height before you read it. AKA you need to loop from last to first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to change the height, you need to read it before you change it. So that means you need to start at the end and work your way to the beginning.

```
var lis = $('ul li');
for(var i=lis.length-1;i>0;i--) {
    lis.eq(i).height( lis.eq(i-1).height() );
}
```

Comment: why dont u use the **reverse()** which it more suitable then this for loop?? check out my answer..!! when jquery already provided the reverse method then i don't think you should use your own for loop.. if you are performance conscious..!!

Comment: @DeepakSharma jQuery DID NOT provide the reverse method. LOL you are using an Array reverse method and making a new jQuery set off that. That is not part of jQuery.

Comment: yeah same thing..  well jquery mean its inside the jquery scope.. in actual its Javascript method..

Comment: @DeepakSharma. It is not the same thing. Why would I not do it? Because it requires multiple loops and this answer is simple. Also requires multiple jQuery object creation. Who cares if it is not chained. If you really want to be cool copy the jQuery reverse plugin and use that. `$('ul li').reverse().each(...)`

Comment: when you have simple way then i dont thin there is any requirement to use the reverse plugin.. when you have simple and inbuilt method then whats the need to use the other plugins and wrote your own code.?? I think its just the timewaste thats it.. so i just suggest.. well its upto you what you want to use.. but i will never prefer or suggest such for loop when i have buildin reverse method.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/hW9ux/

**JS:-**

```
$('ul li').each(function (index) {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.next().attr('data-height', elem.height() + 'px');
});

$('ul li').each(function (index) {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.data("height")) {
        elem.height(elem.data("height"));
        elem.removeData("height");
    }
});
```

**CSS:-**

```
.elem1 {
    height:100px;
}
.elem2 {
    height:200px;
}
.elem3 {
    height:300px;
}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<ul>
    <li class="elem1">Element here</li>
    <li class="elem2">Element here</li>
    <li class="elem3">Element here</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @epascarello If you change the height for next element and in the next iteration it will not reflect it's old value. It will use new assigned  value.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple.. just you the reverse that it..

```
$($("ul li").get().reverse()).each(function(index){
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.next().css('height', elem.height()+'px');
})
```

it will work perfectly.. !! try it

Comment: everything u have written is right.. but the only issue is that.. **for each loop will read from elem1 to elem3, but as per your requirement its clear for each loop should read the elements from elem3 to elem1 so you need to use the reverse() method to reverse the collection.** thats it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ul>
   <li class="elem1">Element here </li> 
   <li class="elem2">Element here </li>  
   <li class="elem3">Element here </li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
var incr, i=0;
$('li').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        incr = $this.height();
    if(i == 0){
        $this.next().height( $this.height());
        i++;
    } else {
        $this.next().height( $this.height()+incr);
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.elem1 {height:100px;}
li {background-color:grey; width:100px;}
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xMGJe/4/